# how to Redirect to a specific div on a different page with smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, smooth-scrolling

I am learning to make a website and while implementing an anchor link on a recipes section with "read" button which is recipes section it redirecting successfully but the issue is how to make a smooth scroll happen?.
Please find the link below https://ginzer2.imfast.io/ and this was made with bootstrap 3. Kindly help to achieve this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
       const elem = document.querySelector('#element_id')
       elem.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'start'
        });
```

Comment: the link is renders to page not found  and can you explain what is the html element there

Comment: still not able to  replicate it smooth scroll is not working. Kindly check the link  https://ginzer2.imfast.io/  provided

Comment: can you try adding this style to the redirected page - 
```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp